# VBA - Sum Cells with the 'Number Stored as Text' error

Tags: excel, vba, sum, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, I am writing VBA to take the `SUM` of a range of filtered values, and store that result into a variable.  The code looks like this:

```
With Sheets("Output")
    .Range("$A:$ZZ").AutoFilter field:=ColIndex(AB), Criteria1:="x"
    y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum( _ 
            Range(Cells(2, "AC"), Cells(10, "AC")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
        )
```

This **does** work, but **only** when I have manually toyed with the data.  When I try to use this formula on my data set unedited, I get a blank result.  The problem seems to lie with the data when unedited.

Each number gets the `Number Stored as Text` (NSaT) error.  Changing the type from `Text` to `General` causes nothing to happen.  I have to open the cell for editing, and then remove focus from the cell for the type to kick in.  After that, I can change it back and forth from `General` to `Text`, and Excel immediately recognizes this and updates the cell.  The Sum function will, at this point, recognize both `General` and `Text` field types as a number.

Is there a VBA solution for dealing with these NSaT errors?  I have attempted to use 'NumberFormat' on the column, but it does not help.  I have also tried manually copying and pasting the data again, even using the special `As Value` option, but it still has the NSaT error until manually toyed with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel: How to force cell evaluation](http://superuser.com/q/299437/52365)

Comment: Ah thank you; it seems to be the case.  I'll test it out and see if it works.  Didn't realize it was called 'Cell Evaluation'!

Comment: Not that it was called "cell evaluation," but this is how the previous guy decided to call it.

Comment: I tried it, but found it need some tweaking.  I included the `c.NumberFormat = "General"` before the `c.Value = c.Value`.  Needed since my file normally comes in with the columns set to text.  But other than that, the `value = value` trick worked perfectly.  Thanks for the help!